# Python Polars: How to delete rows from a DataFrame that match a given Regex?

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I'm working with a Polars DataFrame and I need to delete all the rows of a specific column that contains a given regex.

Using:
`filter = df['col1'].str.contains(regex)`

I'm able to get a Polars Series called filter that contains either True of False if they match the provided regular expresion.

How can I remove the rows that match it?

I'm getting an extra bool column but I'm not able to remove the matches.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```py
df = df.filter(~pl.col('col1').str.contains(regex))
```

Comment: You want a `not` somewhere in there, right? OP wants rows not containing the regex.

Comment: yup thanks, have corrected

Comment: The more important thing to this answer than the negation symbol is to keep the filter expression as an expression and not to generate a Series of bools. Polars isn't pandas and it is an anti pattern to do `df['col1'].str.contains(regex)` instead of `pl.col('col1').str.contains(regex)`

Comment: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/migration/pandas/#selecting-data

Answer (score -1):

To filter out rows that match the regex, use `str.contains` on the column with the problem.

```
m = ~df['q1'].str.contains(r'\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+')
```

df = df[m]

Comment: you should not store a Series of bools. I appreciate that you're adding the ~ to what OP has which answers their question in a literal sense but it's not the intended way to do filters.