# How can I filter all rows of a polars dataframe that partially match strings in another?

Tags: python, python-polars, bulkupdate

I want to delete all rows of a dataframe that match one or more rows in a filtering dataframe.

Yes, I know about filter by [**one** regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77476875/python-polars-how-to-delete-rows-from-a-dataframe-that-match-a-given-regex) and I also know how join can be leveraged when there is a [full match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421496/polars-filter-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-by-row-elements) on a column.  This isn't a direct match, except through looping the filter dataframe row by row.

It is a relatively trivial problem in sql to apply this filter in bulk, on the server, without looping with client-side code:

given:

###### data.csv

```
filename,col2
keep.txt,bar
skip.txt,foo
keep2.txt,zoom
skip3.txt,custom1
discard.txt,custom2
file3.txt,custom3
discard2.txt,custom4
file4.txt,custom5
```

###### filter.csv:

```
skip
discard
skip
```

Here's the sql using postgres.  It will, and that is the key point here, scale very well.

###### withsql.sql

```
\c test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS filter;

CREATE TABLE data (
    filename CHARACTER(50),
    col2 CHARACTER(10),
    skip BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);

\copy data (filename,col2) FROM './data.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV);

CREATE TABLE filter (
    skip VARCHAR(20)
);

\copy filter FROM './filter.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV);

update filter set skip = skip || '%';

update data set skip = TRUE where exists (select 1 from filter s where filename like s.skip);
delete from data where skip = TRUE;

select * from data;
```

`psql -f withsql.sql`

this gives as output:

```
You are now connected to database "test" as user "djuser".
...
UPDATE 4
DELETE 4
                      filename                      |    col2    | skip 
----------------------------------------------------+------------+------
 filename                                           | col2       | f
 keep.txt                                           | bar        | f
 keep2.txt                                          | zoom       | f
 file3.txt                                          | custom3    | f
 file4.txt                                          | custom5    | f
(5 rows)
```

Now, I can do with polars, but the only thing I can think of is using a loop on the filter.csv:

###### withpolars.py

```
import polars as pl

df_data = pl.read_csv("data.csv")
df_filter = pl.read_csv("filter.csv")

for row in df_filter.iter_rows():
    df_data = df_data.filter(~pl.col('filename').str.contains(row[0]))

print("data after:\n", df_data)
```

The output is correct, but I do this without looping, somehow?  And... just curious how some of these bulk sql approaches map to dataframes.

```
data after:
 shape: (4, 2)
┌───────────┬─────────┐
│ filename  ┆ col2    │
│ ---       ┆ ---     │
│ str       ┆ str     │
╞═══════════╪═════════╡
│ keep.txt  ┆ bar     │
│ keep2.txt ┆ zoom    │
│ file3.txt ┆ custom3 │
│ file4.txt ┆ custom5 │
└───────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Which of these tables is bigger, data.csv, or filter.csv? Can you give estimates of number of rows for both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a dedicated partial/substring matching function:

- [`.str.contains_any()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.contains_any.html#polars.Expr.str.contains_any)

```py
df_data.filter(
    pl.col("filename")
      .str.contains_any(df_filter.get_column("skip"))
      .not_()
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 2)
┌───────────┬─────────┐
│ filename  ┆ col2    │
│ ---       ┆ ---     │
│ str       ┆ str     │
╞═══════════╪═════════╡
│ keep.txt  ┆ bar     │
│ keep2.txt ┆ zoom    │
│ file3.txt ┆ custom3 │
│ file4.txt ┆ custom5 │
└───────────┴─────────┘
```

As for your current approach, I think the issue is calling `.filter` each time.

Instead, you would build a single expression and call it once. (allowing Polars to parallelize the work)

```py
df_data.filter(
   pl.all_horizontal(
      pl.col("filename").str.contains(row).not_()
      for row in df_filter.get_column("skip")
   )
)
```

Comment: Nice (do note you need to assign the result, it's not in-place, `df_data = df_data.filter...`.  Didn't know you could look at other dataframes that way.  Much closer to sql than expected :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could always just build the regex manually from the filter df:

```py
data_df = pl.read_csv(data_csv)
filter_df = pl.read_csv(filter_csv, has_header=False, new_columns=["filter"])


filter_re = "|".join(re.escape(s) for s in filter_df.get_column("filter"))

data_df.filter(~pl.col("filename").str.contains(filter_re))
```

Comment: Well, you'd still be looping through filters, regex concatenation is going to be marginally efficient and, I expect, downright iffy at very high filter volumes.